# Investigate reason why MacBook became ultra slow after OS update

Tags: mac, macbook, ios, macos-sierra

I've updated to the latest Sierra (macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6), and now my system is horrible slow.
When I open any program (even repeatedly), it takes like 1-2 minutes to show up, even "System Settings" take really long. When I click on "Purchased item" in iTunes, it takes 30 seconds to show this tab.

Showing the simulator window took around 30 minutes.

I rebooted several times, but the problem persists.

A reboot takes around 5 minutes. During the booting, the progressbar comes to a halt, stalls 1 minute, then the logo becomes white on black background, then the booting continues fast.

I took a look at the Process Watcher, and the CPU is very low:

```
System: 8%
User: 4%
Inactive: 89%
```

Free disk space is 450 GB.

I'm however unsure about the memory:

```
Physical memory: 2 GB
Memory occupied: 1,82 (App memory: 360 MB, Reserved: 886 MB, Compressed: 650 MB)
Files in cache: 173,6 MB
Used swap: 40,8 MB
```

What would be the next steps to investigate why the system is so slow?

Comment: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

Comment: You could have just confirmed said "no".

Comment: What were you on before 10.12.6? Were you still on 10.11 or earlier? Or was this just a minor bump from another 10.12.x version? How long ago did you upgrade?

Comment: I don't know what it was before, I think it was a rather big jump.

Comment: Did you installed any new software after the update?

Comment: No. I just updated Xamarin studio, XCode, Safari and all other softwares that Apple wanted me to update. I didn't install any "new" software.

Comment: This is not an answer but more of information acquired from a Certified Apple Service point. Apple updates do not remove any previous versions, they just go and sit on top of the other. This applies to every apple device, from macbooks, to iphones, ipads etc. My ipad was gradually slowing down (have it for 5 years so I thought it was just old), he said do a factory reset to go to the installed version and then download the newest update. Did that and now it's like new. Every time there is an update i just reset it. Of course I dont know if that's the case with you but it's a thought.

Comment: I've installed a clean SierraHD, and it's still horribly slow. I've followed all the steps mentioned here: http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-to-fix-mac-wont-turn-on-3423817/#toc-3423817-7 However, nothing wrong was detected. During the boot, the logo switches to white, so I guess that means that something goes wrong. So my question remains: How can I log / debug what's causing this slowliness?

Comment: I've reinstalled my MAC with a clean SierraHD, and it turns out that my MacMini is just too old, it has only 2 GB of RAM. It meets the minium requirements, but obviously this is just too slow.

Answer (score 0):

One major cause of slowness after a major macOS upgrade is a bunch of system processes contending for disk access as they update their databases. In my experience this was especially true of the upgrade to Sierra.

- **Spotlight** (mds, mdworker) has to reindex a lot of things because the update changed a lot of files.
- **Time Machine** (backupd) has a lot of new stuff to back up.
- The **Photos** app has a background process that updates your Photo library, such as performing face-recognition and other content recognition using the latest algorithms
- The **Mail** app often needs to rebuild/reindex your mail database after a major update.
- If things like the Photos and Mail reindexing touch a lot of files, Spotlight and Time Machine have even more work to do, so the cycle takes a while to calm down.

When I updated to Sierra, my Time Machine backups didn't complete on my laptop for a few days because there was too much disk contention as Photos was reindexing my large photo library to apply all the new content-recognition algorithms to everything. During this time my machine ran slowly, not because of high CPU usage, but because of disk contention. Everything was I/O-bound, not CPU-bound.

In my case the best solution was to just leave my MacBook Pro up and running (open, plugged into AC power and set to not go to sleep) overnight while all those background processes got all their "things to do after a major OS update" work out of the way. I tend to use my laptop in short sprints and close the lid in between, so the system wasn't getting enough fully-awake-and-running time to get its background tasks done, and Power Nap wasn't cutting it.